# Duplicate files using names from a list

Tags: bash, file, terminal, copy, names

I have a list with 1850 completely different names, like `happy_birthday.js`. Now I want to duplicate that file 1850 times, but each file must have a different name, coming from a list. This list is in the file `song_titles.txt`.

I know how to create folders from a list, like this:

```
xargs -tI % mkdir % < song_titles.txt
```

but I don't know if it is possible to combine renaming with duplicating.

Comment: What shell are you using?

Comment: Mac OSX Yosemite

Comment: I don't quite understand what exactly you refer to when saying "list" and "file". Can you [edit] your question to add a [mcve], i.e., an example directory structure, contents of the various files etc.?

Comment: WIth the 'list' I mean "song_titles.txt" Contents of this list is something like:

Comment: Please update the question, it's hard to read things in comments as they lack most formatting.

Comment: song_titles.txt has vertically listed 1850 song titles and I have 1 file that has javascript content. I want 1850 times the same content, but each file have a different name. These names have to come from song_titles.txt. So if it were to have 2 songs instead of 1850, there would be created 2 files with 2 different names, but with the same content.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178145/discussion-between-benjamin-w-and-jan-de-vries).

Answer (score 1):

When `cp` duplicates a file it can rename it to anything you like.  Try:

```
xargs -tI % cp -- happy_birthday.js % <song_titles.txt
```

Comment: This is the answer.